# Scrapy server setup

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

Im trying to setup a scrapyd server on AWS and am trying to access it from my local machine. So far, ive managed to get scrapyd running on the remote machine.

I know its running because when I do `start scrapyd` i get `start: Job is already running: scrapyd`.

What do I need to do, to be able to access it from my local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ssh` port fowarding:

```
ssh scrapyd.host.com -L 6800:localhost:6800
```

And then access scrapyd at http://localhost:6800 from your local machine.